# Compare datetime accurate to the minute

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

As part of a script, I am attempting to compare what the values in my data were like 5 minutes prior to a given

```py
prev_tstamp = current_timestamp - dt.timedelta(minutes=5)
prev_df = dfc[(dfc.index == prev_tstamp)]
```

The issue here is that I do not care about second level accuracy. I do care about the minute and above (hour, day, week of the year etc.). E.g., I would like if `Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:45:02')` and `Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:45:21')` would return `True` in such a comparision without having to edit the timestamps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can floor a pandas Timestamp value to a frequency (such as each minute), so then they would compare equal

```
prev_df = dfc[(dfc.index.floor('min') == prev_tstamp.floor('min')]
```

This is assuming that all that matters is that the previous timestamp and index value occur within the same minute value

i.e.
Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:45:21') should compare equal with Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:45:02') and Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:45:58') because they all happen with the '6:45' minute

but not with Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:44:58') or Timestamp('2020-01-01 06:46:02')

If instead what you want is to get any row with an index value that occurs within 60 seconds (on either side) of prev_tstamp, you should instead do the following:

```
prev_df = dfc[abs((dfc.index - prev_tstamp).total_seconds()) < 60]
```

Comment: This is actually incorrect. Here is a counter-example: `pd.Timestamp('12:00:31').floor('min') == pd.Timestamp('12:01:29').floor('min')`. This returns False but the difference is only 58 seconds. [@not_speshal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68747376/16343464) is the way to go.

Comment: My understanding of the question is that that SHOULD return False

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
>>> dfc[(dfc.index-prev_tstamp.replace(second=0)).seconds<60]
```